# why git branch -D does not delete local branch

Tags: git

```sh
    $ git checkout -B test 
    $ # change anything
    $ git branch
    $  master
    $  * test
    $ git commit -am 'updated' 
    $ git checkout master 
    $ git branch
    $  * master
    $  test
    $ git branch -D test 
    $ git branch
    $  * master
    $ git checkout test 
    $ git branch
    $  master
    $  * test
```

why no error? like error: pathspec 'test' did not match any file(s) known to git

Comment: `-D` is a shortcut to `-d -f` (force delete), and the “force” part suppresses any errors. Use `-d` or `--delete` if you want to get an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From

```
$ git branch -D test
$ git branch
$  * master
```

we can see the branch **was deleted**. The next command

```
$ git checkout test
```

**recreates** the branch from remote-tracking ref `origin/test`. See [the docs on `git checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt---guess):

> If `<branch>` is not found but there does exist a tracking branch in exactly one remote (call it `<remote>`) with a matching name, treat as equivalent to
>
> $ git checkout -b <branch> --track <remote>/<branch>